# Get a dynamic variable from POST

Tags: php, mysql, forms, variables, dynamic

I want to randomize a number of users selected by an administrator.

So first, I have a page that reads all the name from the "Users" table.  Then I display the names with a checkbox next to it so the admin can deselect names that aren't going to participate.

```
<input name="User<? echo $rows['UserID']; ?>" type="checkbox" value="1" checked/>
```

So, it will set values like User1 = 1; User2 = 0; User3 = 1, and so on...

Next, I want to write to the database the users that were selected in the form so I can read that table again to randomize the participants.  How do I read the dynamic variable from the previous form?  I'm trying to read the variable from the POST and store it in the variable Player (i.e.: User1 value is stored in Player1 variable)... this but doesn't seem to work:

```
    $x = 1;
while ($x <= $total_records) {
    ${"Player" . $x} = $_POST[ ${"User" . $x} ];
    $x++;
    echo "Player" . $x . " = " . ${"Player" . $x} . "<BR>";
}
```

The result is "Player1 = ", "Player2 = ".  Always empty.

Any idea, or an easier way to do it? ;)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a separate approach. Instead of creating a different name for each checkbox, how about making them an array and their values are the users' ids?

For instance:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="User[]" value="<? echo $rows['UserID']; ?>" />
```

Then, you'll only have to iterate over the submitted array:

```
if (isset($_POST['User']) && is_array($_POST['User'])) {
    foreach ($_POST['User'] as $userId) {
        // do something with the user id!
    }
}
```

If you want to keep the list as, well, a "list" to be reused, you could [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) the array that's posted and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) when you need to use it again:

```
$combinedIds = implode(',', $_POST['User']);
// now you have 1,3,17

$splitIds = explode(',', $combinedIds);
// now you have array(1, 3, 17)
```

You can store the list in the db, a session variable, etc. If you store in a session variable, you could also directly store the array (whichever's easier =P).

Comment: That sounds real great.  So if I can handle the arry without having to write the participants in the database, I guess it would be better to replace "UserID" by "UserName" directly as I will not need the UserID to shuffle the list.  So if I change the form to set the value to UserName instead of UserID, will it still work?  I'm just not sure what User[] is doing in the form...

Comment: @Andrewww Yeah, you can replace `UserId` with whatever unique identifier you want; I would recommend against using their actual names unless the names are strictly unique though. `User[]`, in terms of HTML form elements, means that all elements that share that name are part of an "array" named `User`. When the form is submitted, it will submitted as a usable array to save you the work of having to create one yourself =]

Comment: Damn.. I'm unable to deal with the results.  Been trying for 1 hour, nothing to do.  Can you help, I would just like to shuffle that array (from the POST) and display the result without using print_r (the output sucks using this!)

Comment: @Andrewww You can use [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle) to shuffle the array; then, just loop over it (`foreach ($users as $user) { echo $user . '<br />'; }`). If you're having difficulties with that, you may need to post a separate answer to keep them each focused on a specific topic.